# What model of bike does Jock use in the film Young Offenders

Tags: identify-this-bike, movie

[image]

Its the guy on the left / red bike if you have not seen the film. For that matter any of the bikes jack uses in the film would be good to know.

**White Bike**

[image: From https://www.cinemaclock.com/movies/the-young-offenders-2016]

**Black Bike**

[image: From https://www.breakingnews.ie/discover/young-offenders-tour-of-cork-on-the-cards-829738.html]

**Yellow Bike**

[image: From https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4714568/mediaindex?ref_=tt_pv_mi_sm]

**More bikes**

[image: From https://www.rte.ie/brainstorm/2018/0404/952162-heres-what-criminologists-make-of-the-young-offenders/]

Comment: I guess the more photos you can supply the better, within reason. I haven’t seen the film

Comment: @Swifty googling about shows there are a lot of bikes in this film - couldn't find another shot of the red bike though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some moving clips  at [broken-link] but blurring detracts from the details

The red bike seems to be too small for the rider - which may be because he's just stolen it and has not adjusted to fit his height.  Noted it has a front suspension and a disk brake.

Also, most of the bikes used in the film look like BSO MTBs with front suspension - that is they're hard tails.  Also noted that only a couple of them have disk brakes - rim brakes being a mark of a BSO.  That's odd because one might presume a bike thief would steal the nicest bike they could, which would have a higher resale value.

The masks are an excellent idea for hiding the face of stunt riders, but riding in a rubber hood would be horrible in practice, due to sweat and limited visibility.

Specific to the Yellow town bike "It's a girls bike - its got the fanny dip thing"   from [broken-link].  It also has a 3 speed nexus internally geared hub at 68 seconds.

There's a brown mixte frame in the back of one shot - that looks like an 80s bike.

All in all, it looks like the bikes have been chosen to be representative of a low-income area, where old bikes live for years, and nobody would own an expensive bike.

Comment: Cheers thankyou for taking your time to find out this information!

Comment: @SamPhelps Looks like a worthy film to watch - but I couldn't understand much of the dialogue.... almost needs subtitles for my foreign ear.

Comment: Haha yeah i would recommend watching it its great, the first bike scene is sick. Thats the bike i wanted to see what model it was. Thanks again for your time man !

Comment: Perhaps fewer BSOs than first thought, and in supporting roles; I’ve name dropped some decent brands. I suspect the bikes on a movie set need to meet a certain standard with safety and liability a big concern. Even that brown mixte looks in good shape for a ‘40’ year old bike. The one that shoots by down all those steps (in that clip) is a serious rig!

Comment: The links are now broken.

Answer (score 3):

Red bike looks to me like an [On One Inbred](https://images.app.goo.gl/RDoufY91czJcE4R88), the head tube logo looks similar and the rear seat stays have a distinctive design.

[image]<sub>Image source: [Chris Berkley](https://chrisberkley.com/blog/custom-one-inbred-frame-build-part-1/)</sub>

Then the forks could be Rock Shox and brakes may be Avids, but v hard to tell with the image resolution (bikes aren’t the focus of the shots to be fair). Note that if you want one it’ll have to be second hand as the bike is [discontinued](https://www.on-one.co.uk/news/products/q/date/2017/10/25/the-inbred-is-dead).

I would say the white bike has Fox forks and Maxxis tyres so pretty good spec, but hard to say more. Paint job looks quite distinctive, anyone?

The black bike I’m more confident is a Giant (hardtail), from the head tube logo. Hydraulic brakes again, presumably for the stunt work.

Yellow bike is an [Electra Amsterdam Classic 3i Step Through](https://images.app.goo.gl/ayUtUq6XeDD5SqXg8), which are made by Trek it seems. Saddle swapped to something more old school. Note single cable from handlebars to gears, no brake levers - must be a coaster brake.

[image] <sub>Image source: [rei.com](https://www.rei.com/product/781238/electra-amsterdam-classic-3i-step-through-womens-bike)</sub>

Then the ‘other bikes’ photo, his is a fast looking flat bar road bike, looks like a nice bike but can’t say what. The brown mixte Criggie refers to I think is a Raleigh, looks like the heron head badge. Probably sometime around 1980. The two others are BSO contenders, silver/red for sure, purple one could be an older entry level bike from a good brand.

Answer (score 2):

The white bike is full suspension bike by “transition”
Pause the film a few mins in just after the young offenders title comes up in yellow
Pause it 2 secs after that and you can read it yourself